# Are there any release notes about FSharp.Core 4.3.4?

Tags: f#

What changed between v4.3.0 and 4.3.4 of FSharp.Core?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core/

or

https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp

do not list what changes or fixes are included.

Comment: the github repo would be the right place to ask.